# Mapbox markers - customize size of clickable area

Tags: android, mapbox

I am using Mapbox markers on Android with custom icons. My icons seem to be larger than standard markers though, which results in part of the icon not being clickable (the user needs to touch the center of the icon to actually invoke the click event).

How can I "grow" the clickable area to match my icon?

Comment: try this code .. and also read documenation....   https://www.mapbox.com/help/android-markers/                                                                                              mapboxMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new MapboxMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
});

Comment: Please read the question carefully. The code you've shown handles marker click events. So does mine. The problem lies in something else - the clickable area is much small for my marker icons.

Comment: there is no option in mapbox or other maps api for (clickable area)....

Answer (score 0):

I just happened across a somewhat similar issue earlier tonight.  My custom icons are very small, making hitting them difficult.  My fix was to embed my icon in a larger PNG file, with the added area set to be transparent.  I wanted a small marker (10 x 10 pixels); by padding the icon to 24 x 24, the target area is now very usable.

I've verified this with very large icons... they work all the way out to the corners, whether transparent or not. Possibly your original issue has simply been fixed in the Android SDK? (question is now four months old)

One note on the transparent padding approach for small icons, though: you may need to adjust your anchor for the marker to keep the original, non-transparent pixels in the correct location.  In my case, the marker was originally centered (0.5, 0.5), so increasing the icon size by padding evenly all around with transparent pixels didn't change the original anchor U and V values.